# Android array of ids to reference textViews

Tags: android, arrays, dynamic, textview

I have a screen with 24 TextViews that I want to change values of. It doesn't matter in which order I just need to change the value from every text field. Right now my code is as follows:

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView.setText(value1);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView.setText(value2);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
textView.setText(value3);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
textView.setText(value4);
etc...
```

The number of TextViews is constant at 24. I am looking for a loop solution however the issue I run into is dynamically getting the R.id.textViewX value id. Is there a simple way to accomplish this so that I can use it in the following manner:

```
// Somehow get textViewArray of textView id's //

for(int i=0;i<textViewArray.length;i++) {
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(textViewArray[i]);
  textView.setText(value[i])
}
```

I'm open to the idea of dynamically creating the textfields in the Activity class but am looking for an XML solution. I'm not sure if this can be done using the arrays class. I've seen this done for @drawables but never for id's

Important to note is that the textView's are NOT in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
     int id = getResources().getIdentifier("textView" + i, "id", getPackageName());
     TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(id);
     textView.setText("Set text");
}
```